# SQL Check for Violation FRAUD Voters

Tags: sql

I am trying to check if there are any ballots made by a voter that is not a resident of a state.

So the final SQL query is to pull up all the ballots that were voted by a voter that is not a resident of that state

The database is setup as

```
voter (id, name, profile_photo, email, address)

ballot (id, date, add_group)
add_group FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES state (name) 

state (name, create_voter)
create_voter FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES voter (id)

resident_of (id, name)
id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES voter (id)
name FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES state (name)

voted (name, ballot_id, voter_id)
name FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES state (name)
ballot_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ballot (id)
voter_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES voter (id)
```

Comment: It would seem that you would need dates if you are actually attempting to do something useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select T1.*, T2.*, T3.*
 from  voted T1
  join resident_of T2
   ON  T1.voter_id = T2.id 
  left join voter T3
   ON  T1.voter_id = T3.id
Where T1.name <> T2.name;
```

EDIT : As per the schema provided in the question, there is a column "name" in the table voted that refers to the state specific to the vote/ballot and the column "name" in the table resident_of represents the state (state name) where voter resides. The query above compares these 2 columns with appropriate joins and returns the details for those records where these names (i.e. States in these 2 tables) are different for a specific voter which I believe was asked in the question.

Comment: How does this help determine if there is a fraud. The OPs question is to find out if the vote is by someone outside the state. Also, i would recommend reading [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27320208)

Comment: @JoeFerndz - Why do you think this does not provide answer to the question?

Comment: @JoeFerndz - Please read the table schema in question. The column "name" refer to the name of states. There is a column "name" in the table voted that refers to the state specific to the vote/ballot and the column "name" in the table resident_of represents the state where voter resides. The query above compares the 2 with appropriate joins and returns the details for those records where these names (i.e. States in these 2 tables) are different which was asked in the question.

Comment: I recommend you explain this in the answer section so it is easier for people to understand how the query works.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the explanation of the query logic. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted as this provides additional context to the code.